# Derivation or historical existence of the phrase: "I will do my possible."

Tags: expressions, british-english, nineteenth-century-english, eighteenth-century-english

I've been reading Georgette Heyer again and find this sentence coming up: "I will do my possible."

*The Reluctant Widow*

Chapter 17

“Perhaps. **I shall do my possible**. You have been troubled with him for too long.”

https://litbit.ru/en/georgette-heyer/the-reluctant-widow

*The Quiet Gentleman*

Chapter 11

“Nor I, but **I shall do my possible**. Both injury and scandal I should dislike quite as much as you, Theo, I assure you."

https://litbit.ru/en/georgette-heyer/the-quiet-gentleman

*The Toll-Gate*

Chapter 13

“Yes, a contemptible creature! But I promised his grandfather **I would do my possible** to keep his name clean!”

https://litbit.ru/en/georgette-heyer/the-toll-gate

Does anyone know if this is an 18th or 19th century common phrase? I'm doing this before looking for concordances of 18th and 19th century authors. Though, I don't know if there are any such concordances in existence for those authors.

Curiosity drives this because I find that I like the phrase very much for it's realistic view of one's sphere of influence or agency.

Thank you.

Comment: Please indicate what research you've done. It's very easy to search [Google Book](https://books.google.com/), for example.

Comment: It seems like a literal translation of the (more common) French expression _Je ferai mon possible_.

Comment: Good question. The expression appears in several Google Books matches from the 1700s, including a [letter written in 1759](https://books.google.com/books?id=0N01AQAAMAAJ&pg=PA93&dq=%22do+my+possible%22&hl=en&newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiru_j-ppH6AhV0ADQIHWW9CUcQ6AF6BAgCEAI#v=onepage&q=%22do%20my%20possible%22&f=false). It would be interesting to know when this idiomatic form arose and when it fell out of usage (as it seems to have done). I have never encountered it in the wild nor (until today) in books.

Comment: Evidently, Robert Louis Stevenson was sufficiently familiar with the expression to put it in the mouth of Long John Silver in [_Treasure Island_](https://babel.hathitrust.org/cgi/pt?id=uc1.31175035209256&view=1up&seq=317&q1=%22do%20my%20possible%22) (written in 1881–1882 but set in the 1700s): "Why, sir, **I do my possible**, which that aint,” said Silver. “I can only, asking your pardon, save my life and the boy's by seeking for that treasure; and you may lay to that."

Comment: Sounds like the current Indian-English *Please do the needful*.

Comment: Hello, all. Thanks so much for your replies.